# Update labels periodically

Tags: android

On most of activities in my app there's a label - on air stream title. Essentially, I need to update it when a broadcast ends and another one starts and I have schedule for that. I could just update data at fixed rate, say one time per minute, but I find it excessive.

I want to schedule update for particular moment in time; after each update I need to schedule next one. Broadcasts are different in time range.

What is the best fit for this issue? Handler.postDelayed, ScheduledExecutorService.schedule or  something else? AlarmManager is probably an overkill since I don't need to update any data if application isn't running.

p.s. time range is not fixed, so I have to alter schedule time with each update.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that using a `Handler.postDelayed` is a better option, since you can vary the delay. Using a Timer of any kind conflicts with the "varying length" requirement.

Comment: If time range is not fixed then `Handler.postDelayed` is better choice.

Comment: Handler is **always** the better choice with Android, as Timer isn't officially supported (or rather, not recommended)

Comment: There is the Android CountDownTimer, which is nice, but not for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) is best choice in this case. Use it with [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html).

Comment: and you better use fixed-period execution instead of fixed-rate execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use thread to update data periodically here this thread will run for 2 seconds, by calling this function inside loops you can periodically update things

```
Strinh hello="HI";
    final int _splashTime = 2000; // time to display the splash screen in ms

    Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if(_active) {
                        waited += 100;
                    }                      
                }

            } 
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
            } 
            finally {
                finish();
               hello="HI2";
                stop();
            }
        }
    };
    splashTread.start();
```

here the string hello will change from HI to HI2 in 2 seconds

Hope this helps you